# What is the difference between MibSPI and SPI?

Tags: spi, texas-instruments, serial-bus

The following text is from the TI TMS570LC4357 microcontroller features overview:

> - Five Multibuffered Serial Peripheral Interface (MibSPI) Modules
>
>   - MibSPI1: 256 Words with ECC Protection
>   - Other MibSPIs: 128 Words with ECC Protection

MibSPI seems to be a Texas Instruments term.
What is the difference between MibSPI vs SPI?

The physical layer is the same, right?
Can I connect standard SPI devices to the MibSPI module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Reference Document](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spnu217b/spnu217b.pdf):

> This reference guide provides the specifications for a 16-bit
> configurable synchronous multi-buffer serial peripheral interface
> (MibSPI). The MibSPI is, in effect, a programmable-length shift
> register used for high speed communication between external
> peripherals or other microcontrollers. Its multi-buffer allows
> multiple transmissions with different peripherals without any CPU
> action.

It kind of is for your µc SPI communication what DMA is for memory, it allows you to offload some work from the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Standard SPI communication doesn't support individual setting for communication with each of the Slave devices connected with the master device. However with the MiBSPI(Multi-Buffer SPI), the setting for each slave can be done depending on which I/O device is connected to a particular Slave line.For example, if there is sensor on one SPI slave line supporting 10MHz Clock frequency(Fast Slave) and there is another Slave device requiring 5MHz(Slow Device), the MiBSPI provides control registers to do these settings during the initialization. There are also some other useful settings like inter-frame delay time, SPI mode, data direction etc. which can be set individually for each slave device. The device - TMS470R1x supports the MiBSPI mode of SPI communication